# System.setproperties not setting the keystore path JAVA

Tags: java, keystore

I have set the Keystore path in JAVA by using System.property("key","value") method

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\taqeem.gov.sa.key");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "QimaP2014");
```

But this doesn't pick the Keystore. What is wrong in it? Any help will be greatly appreciated as I'm out of luck from past 1 week

Comment: .key is a strange extension for a java keystore (would expect .jks) where did you get it from? Did you import cert & key into one?

Comment: actually its type is JKS I checked it with keytool for its type and I'm using this for webApp to be browsed with https I can declare System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS"); but still it doesn't work

Comment: You need to set it before any `SSLContext` is created, implicitly or explicitly. It's only read once in all probability.

Comment: Webapp.. which container are you using? Tomcat, Jetty, java HttpExchange...?

Comment: Its Tomcat and can you please tell me how to set it before SSLContext. Actually I have created the WSDL Java code to call webservice but I literally didn't set the SSL context.